# Hashmap value changes during execution

Tags: java, android, hashmap

I'm using Hashmap in my code to save some datas. I'm using following code

```
HashMap<Integer,ArrayList<Friends>> friendsHashMap = new HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<Friends>>();
...
...
ArrayList<Friends> friendsArrayList = new ArrayList<Friends>();
JSONArray jsonArray = (JSONArray) response.get("friends");
for (int i=0; i<jsonArray.length(); i++){
        JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
        Friend friend = new Friend(jsonObject);
        friendsArrayList.add(friend);
       }

friendsHashMap.put(id,friendsArrayList); //Adding data to hash map
Log.d("friendsHashMap",friendsHashMap.toString());
Log.d("friendsArrayList ",friendsArrayList.size()+""); //Till this line previously loaded data remain normal
friendsLocationMapFragment.drawMap(friendsArrayList); //Once this line is executed the previously added data in the hashmap value changes to empty array.
```

What mistake am I doing?

Comment: Where do you define `id` as the key for the hashmap?

Comment: It is a global value. `id` is an integer and it changes before these lines of code are executed.

Comment: Are you sure about that?

Comment: yeah. There is no problem with the value that is added to the hashmap at the point. The previously added value of a key changes to emty array.

Comment: What does drawMap do to the array passed to it?

Comment: It gets the array list and places a marker for each item in the array list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be `drawMap(friendsArrayList)`; method putting data to friendsHashMap with same Id as you put data before on this line `friendsHashMap.put(id,friendsArrayList); //Adding data to hash map`

if key are same then HashMap will override previous value with new one.

If you have sure that  key values are unique in hashmap then there is one possibility, inside drawMap(friendsArrayList) may be you are clearing friendsArrayList or removing element or assign new empty list to friendsArrayList, because you passing same references of  list to drawMap

Comment: @Rani may you are clearing friendsArrayList inside drawMap coz you are passing same referees of list to it

Comment: drawmap function is in a fragment. I have another arraylist there and i'm assigning this array list to that. and everytime I call this function I'm clearing the existing array list before assinging this one.

Comment: that's why you are getting empty list. 100% sure. I think you did read my updated answer